# about context object in map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can anyone explain why we are writing arguments in angle brackets in below statement and why we are defining output key/value pairs in arguments.

```
public static class Map extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

What is context object and why we are using in the below statement.

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Answer (score 0):

<> is used to indicate **generics** in Java.

Mapper `<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>` takes only `<LongWritable,Text>` as keys and `<Text,IntWritable>` as values. If you try to provide any other writable types to your mapper, this will throw an error.

`Context` context object is used to write output `Key-Values` as well as get `configuration, counters, cacheFiles` etc in the `Mapper`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Vasu answered..

Context stores references to `RecordReader` and `RecordWriter`. 
Whenever `context.getCurrentKey()` and `context.getCurrentValue()` are used to retrieve key and value pair, the request is assigned to `RecordReader`. And when `context.write()` is called, it is assigned to `RecordWriter`.

Here `RecordReader` and `RecordWrite`r are actually abstract classes.